# In React, is it possible to override just the HTML template, not the entire class?

Tags: reactjs, kibana

The class in question is Card from Elastic UI - [full source](https://github.com/elastic/eui/blob/master/src/components/card/card.js). If description text contains a `div`, this error message is generated:
`Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>.` Unlike the OuterElement, the type of which is dynamically picked, `<p>{description}</p>` is always `p` tag. How could I replace just the `<p>...</p>` part of the template with `<div>...</div>` without overriding the whole class?

```
return (
    <OuterElement
      onClick={onClick}
      className={classes}
      href={href}
      target={target}
      rel={secureRel}
      {...rest}
    >
      {optionalBetaBadge}

      {optionalCardTop}

      <span className="euiCard__content">
        <EuiTitle className="euiCard__title">
          <span>{title}</span>
        </EuiTitle>

        <EuiText size="s" className="euiCard__description">
          <p>{description}</p>
        </EuiText>
      </span>

      {layout === 'vertical' &&
        <span className="euiCard__footer">
          {footer}
        </span>
      }
    </OuterElement>
  );
```

Comment: You would have to overwrite the whole class.
In what scenario's does the description obtain a `<div>` element? The way the React class was created (looking at the naming of the prop) suggests that the description prop is just blank text. Are you sure you're using the class accordingly?

Comment: Thank you @Alserda, I appreciate your answer. The point of the question is overriding the template, not discussing use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible without overriding the entire class